# Many to Many Relationship Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many

I am working on a `laravel-4` application. Currently It is coming together nicely and I've been getting my head around defining the relationships between the various table s of the database. However I've run into a problem that I'm having trouble solving.

In my db there is a resources table and tags table. There is a many to many relationship between them so I've also got  a resource_tags table which has both tables `id` as the `foreign keys`.

Now, when I am creating a resource based on data provided by the user via a form I create the resource, check the type and decide on an action. Then I retrieve the tags of the resource and loop through them and create an entry into the `Tags` table.

My issue is placing information into the resource_tags table. Is there a method that can enable me to do this with relative ease?

This is my `controller` that is handling the form submission:

```
class SharedResourcesController extends BaseController {
    //Add a shared Resource to the DB
    //To do: Error checking and validation. 
    public function handleResource(){

        //Create Object
        $resource = new SharedResource;
        $resource->title = Input::get('title'); //Title of resource
        $resource->user_id = Input::get('user_id'); //User who uploads
        $resource->book_id = Input::get('book_id'); //Book it is associated with
        $resource->type_id = Input::get('type_id'); //Type of resource

        //STORE LINKS
        //if type is link... 1
        if($resource->type_id == "1"){
            $resource->web_link = Input::get('link');
        }
        //if type is video...2
        if($resource->type_id == "2"){
            $resource->vid_link = Input::get('link');
        }
        //UPLOADING
        //If type is doc...3
        if($resource->type_id == "3"){
            if(Input::hasFile('file')){
                $destinationPath = '';
                $filename = '';
                $file = Input::file('file');
                $basename = Str::random(12);
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $destinationPath = public_path().'/file/';
                $filename = Str::slug($basename, '_').".".$extension;//Create the filename
                $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                $resource->doc_link = $filename;
            }
        }
        //if type is img...4
        if($resource->type_id == "4"){
            if(Input::hasFile('file')){
                $destinationPath = '';
                $filename = '';
                $file = Input::file('file');
                $basename = Str::random(12);
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $destinationPath = public_path().'/img/uploads/';
                $filename = Str::slug($basename, '_').".".$extension;//Create the filename
                $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                $resource->img_link = $filename;
            }
        }

        //TAGS 
        //Get the tags
        $tags = Array();
        $tags = explode(',', Input::get('tags'));
        foreach($tags as $tag){
            //Create a new Tag in DB - TO DO: Only Unique TAGS
            $newTag = new Tag;
            $newTag->name = $tag;
            $newTag->save();
            //Enter to resource tags
        }

        //Entry to resouce_tags

        //Save Object
        $resource->save();
        return Redirect::action('User_BaseController@getSharedResources')->with('success', 'Resouce Created!');

        //Any errors return to Form...
    }
}
```

`MODELS`

```
class SharedResource extends Eloquent{
    //set up many to many
    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
```

and

```
class Tag extends Eloquent{
    //set up many to many
    public function sharedResources(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('SharedResource');
    }
```

I know that there is lots missing in terms of validation and error handling, but I'm just trying to get the flow working and I can modify it at a later date. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you asking if you can save many Tags to a specific Resource all at once, while also inserting those pivot relationships into the resource_tag pivot table?

Comment: yes exactly that is what I need to do

Comment: By the way, as far as I know, your pivot table should use singulars if you want Laravel to be able to work it out: `resource_tag` rather than `resource_tags`. That said, you're obviously already overriding table name as your `resources` table's model is called `SharedResource`.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is build or grab the Resource and build or grab the Tags then call saveMany on the resource's tags relationship and pass an array of tag items into it, like this (pseudo-codey example):

```
$resource = Resource::create(['name' => 'Resource 1']);
$tag = [];
for ($i = 5; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $tag = Tag::create(['name' => 'Tag '.$i]);
    array_push($tags, $tag);
}
$resource->tags()->saveMany($tags);
```

The $tags have to be an array of Tag objects, and the saveMany called on the relationship will take care of the pivot table insertions for you. You should end up with a Resource 1 resource in the resources table, five Tags in the tag table, and 5 records in the resource_tag table with the relationships saved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the code for both of your models as well? Do you have the relationship defined in them?

For example:

```
class Resource  extends Eloquent {

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('tag');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Tag  extends Eloquent {

    public function resources()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('resource');
    }
}
```